# Laravel Eloquent - How to manually append accessor/attribute to result

Tags: eloquent

I have an accessor/attribute  ( `public function getGalleryAttribute()` ) that adds an array of images to the model

I used to eager load this with:  `protected $appends = ['gallery']` , but I got rid of it to be able to control when I want to append the gallery or not.

I can append the gallery to a single model:

```
$event = Event::find(126)->append('gallery');
```

But how do I manually append an accessor when there is more than one result?
This doesn't work:

```
$events = Event::all()->append('gallery');
return $events;
```

error:

```
BadMethodCallException: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::append does not exist
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Eloquent 5.5 or later, you can use `Collection::each` to append to each item:

```
$events = Event::all()->each->append('gallery');
```

You should also look into [Eloquent: API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-resources) to define alternative serialization options for the same model.